# Record and playback audio in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, audio, audio-recording

I have been searching high and low and am at the point of desperation. What I am trying to accomplish is to simply record audio from the microphone, save it to a file and then play it back. Things I have tried:

- Command line audio recording. I found a couple options but NONE that I could get to work.
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210067 I think this would work in XP but not on Vista/7.
- http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_26416850.html (You can get the full thing by clicking [Here](http://www.google.com/search?q=vba%20record%20audio) then it was the 5th one down for me.) This solution runs without a hitch but never records anything.

Like I said, I am open to about anything that I can automate using any terrible tricks anyone can think of. Any suggestions? *Come on SO, you can save me again... :-)*

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but I landed here several times in my search for a solution to record audio with vba. I finally found a solution on http://www.vbarchiv.net I would like to share:
Put this in a module, lets name it sndmodule:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

REM found at http://www.vbarchiv.net

Public Declare Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" _
    (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Const SND_SYNC = &H0
Const SND_ASYNC = &H1
Const SND_FILENAME = &H20000

Public Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "mciSendStringA" ( _
  ByVal lpstrCommand As String, _
  ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, _
  ByVal uReturnLength As Long, _
  ByVal hwndCallback As Long) As Long

Public Enum BitsPerSec
  Bits16 = 16
  Bits8 = 8
End Enum

Public Enum SampelsPerSec
  Sampels8000 = 8000
  Sampels11025 = 11025
  Sampels12000 = 12000
  Sampels16000 = 16000
  Sampels22050 = 22050
  Sampels24000 = 24000
  Sampels32000 = 32000
  Sampels44100 = 44100
  Sampels48000 = 48000
End Enum

Public Enum Channels
  Mono = 1
  Stereo = 2
End Enum

Public Sub play(file As String)
  Dim wavefile
  wavefile = file
  Call sndPlaySound(wavefile, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
End Sub


Public Sub StartRecord(ByVal BPS As BitsPerSec, _
  ByVal SPS As SampelsPerSec, ByVal Mode As Channels)

  Dim retStr As String
  Dim cBack As Long
  Dim BytesPerSec As Long

  retStr = Space$(128)
  BytesPerSec = (Mode * BPS * SPS) / 8
  mciSendString "open new type waveaudio alias capture", retStr, 128, cBack
  mciSendString "set capture time format milliseconds" & _
    " bitspersample " & CStr(BPS) & _
    " samplespersec " & CStr(SPS) & _
    " channels " & CStr(Mode) & _
    " bytespersec " & CStr(BytesPerSec) & _
    " alignment 4", retStr, 128, cBack
  mciSendString "record capture", retStr, 128, cBack
End Sub

Public Sub SaveRecord(strFile)
  Dim retStr As String
  Dim TempName As String
  Dim cBack As Long
  Dim fs, F

  TempName = strFile 'Left$(strFile, 3) & "Temp.wav"
  retStr = Space$(128)
  mciSendString "stop capture", retStr, 128, cBack
  mciSendString "save capture " & TempName, retStr, 128, cBack
  mciSendString "close capture", retStr, 128, cBack

End Sub
```

In your code you can use it like this:

```
Private Sub StartRecord_Click()
  sndmodule.StartRecord Bits16, Sampels32000, Mono
End Sub

Private Sub EndRecord_Click()
  sndmodule.SaveRecord "C:\Users\Johanness\Downloads\test.wav"
End Sub

Private Sub Play_Click()
  sndmodule.play "C:\Users\Johanness\Downloads\test.wav"
End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up using an external .exe file which obviously isn't a very good solution. It isn't pressing right now so it may be a while, but I will probably see if I can get this to work. Thanks a lot for posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Maby this will help:

http://www.ehow.com/how_7889013_use-vba-access-capture-audio.html

Comment: That is the page that links to the MS KB article that I linked. It didn't work. :-(